# stoppropagation not working jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, checkbox

stopPropagation not working with my JQuery Mobile mobile application..

My Code:

Html:

```
<ul id="tmpl">
<li>
<div  class="favorite">
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="sortList" class="checkboxGroup" data-role="none">
 <i></i>
</label>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$(document).on("vclick","#tmpl li",function(){
alert("li clicked");
});

$(document).on("vclick",".favorite i",function(e){
alert("checkbox clicked");
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

css:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + i:before {
    content:'\e809';
    color:lightgray;
    font-family: "icon-font"; font-style : normal; text-shadow:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + i:before {
    content:'\e809';
    color:red;
    font-family: "icon-font"; font-style : normal; text-shadow:none;
}
```

When try to click the checkbox getting alert as checkbox clicked after that immediately it alert as li clicked. But i need  checkbox clicked alert message only when i try to click checkbox.

and also tried use  `$(document).on("vclick", ".favorite", function(e) {})` instead of `$(document).on("vclick", ".favorite i", function(e) {});`

this is working fine. but this method execute twice when it click.

Can u advice me how to solve this issue

lib

- jquery-2.1.1.min.js
- jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js

Answer (score 3):

I had similer issue and it resolved with using stopImmediatePropagation() method instead of stopPropagation().

Please try to use

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Instead of

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the function on the document, which makes is go all the way to the top of the DOM and then searches down the tree. Instead, trigger the `vclick` event directly on the elements.

Change you're code to:

```
$("#tmp li").on("vclick",function(){
    alert("li clicked");
});

$(".favorite i").on("vclick",function(e){
    alert("checkbox clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also, check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/0v34ut9n/)

Comment: no he's not, the second arg he passes to on specify a selector that the event should be applied on